# Generating Python code from OpenAPI spec that recieves a "handler" object

Tags: python, openapi, thrift, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I have an OpenAPI spec that I successfully turned into Server/Client Python code using OpenAPI generator. However the structure of the server does not really fit my needs. To specify how to handle request (say method .foo()), I need to modify a file inside the generated code called "default_controller.py". I'd much rather generate a Python object that specifies the method .foo() and give this to the generated code which turns this into a valid server.

```
class HandlerClass:
    
    def foo(self):
        print("Performing foo")
    
    def bar(self):
        print("Performing bar")
        

handler = HandlerClass()

server = GenerateServerFromHandler(handler)
```

I know this is possible within the Thrift API-spec but unfortunately this is not quite the right tool for the job. Is it possible to generate code like this?

Answer (score 0):

The `openapi-generator` generated code can be customized in several ways as described [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/customization.md), depending on which generator you are using:

- You can download one or more of the default template files (e.g. see
  [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/python-flask) for the python-flask generator) and modify them, then point
  `openapi-generator` to them with the `--template-dir` argument.
- You can customize each generator in several ways via a generator-specific
  config file.
- If you want an entirely different generated structure,
  you can write your own custom generator as described [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/customization.md#custom-generator-and-template).